# Polar 2nd Order Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, cylindrical-coordinates

I have the following differential equation resulting from a simplification of Navier-Stokes in cylindrical coordinates.
$$
\frac{d^2 u_{\theta}}{d r^2}+\frac{d}{dr} \bigg(\frac{u_{\theta}}{r}\bigg)=0
$$
where $u_{\theta}$ is only a function of $r$. This is actually a simplified version using a reverse chain rule for the second term which I thought could help. Does this have a solution and how would you go about solving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{d^2 u}{d r^2}+\frac{d}{dr} \bigg(\frac{u}{r}\bigg)=\frac{d^2 u}{d r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{du}{dr}-\frac{1}{r^2}u=0
$$
Particular solutions on the form $y=r^k$
$$k(k-1)r^{k-2}+\frac{1}{r}kr^{k-1}-\frac{1}{r^2}r^k \quad\to\quad k(k-1)+k-1=0 \quad\to\quad k=\pm 1$$
The two independent solutions $r^1$ and $r^{-1}$ lead to the general solution :
$$u=c_1r+c_2\frac{1}{r}$$

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot. So how did you know to assume $y=r^k$ for the P.I. ? Would you recommend any kind of handbook for this kind of stuff? We get a lot of analytical simplifications of this sort and although we did common PDEs using sep of variables, this kind of 'simple' ODEs are always the challenging ones.

Comment: They are some well known kind of differential equations which have to be studied at early stage of learning. This one is the Cauchy–Euler equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation